# CSS: Google Chrome Labs container-query-polyfill executing 'matches' on 'Element'

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to use container-query-polyfill to make tailwindcss-container-query (TailwindCSS plugin) work. This is all in a react project hosted with vite.js.

tailwindcss-container-query: https://github.com/dgknca/tailwindcss-container-query

**I am getting these errors**

[image: errors]

Comment: Kinda hard to determine without any code. Looks like you installed the polyfill correctly. Did you install the tailwind plugin in the tailwind.config.js? Kinda looks like you have some misplaced @media code, but again, hard to tell.